# EditorFor AdditionalViewData not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
```

This display my user name but I want to override this name. So I tried this :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { value = "othertext"} )
```

But this doesn't work, I always have my user name.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "additional view data" parameter on EditorFor sets up new view data to be used by your editor template(s). It does not make "extra objects" to be rendered as you seem to be using it here.

And as I understand you trying to set `htmlAttributes`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { value = "xxx" })
```

Comment: Yes I don't want to create a new object, but just use the value in the additional view data and not the value returned by the model.

Comment: @MaT `EditorTemplates` is special folder for strongly typed views and as I understand `Password` is `string`, use `TextBox`. How `EditorTemplates` looks: [Quick Tips About ASP.NET MVC – Editor Templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx)